# How to return unique records between two tables without using distinct and union?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to return the unique records between two tables. Ideally, an UNION would solve my problem but both tables contain an object field which gives me an error(cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method) when I do UNION/distinct.

So, I was wondering if I can do a UNION ALL(to avoid the error) to get all the records first then do something to return only the unique records from there. I tried analytic function combined with the UNION ALL query but no luck so far.

```
Select * from Table1
union all
Select * from table2
```

Any help? Note:I need to return all fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved the problem using analytic function+row_num. The query will choose the first record for each set of duplicates hence returning only the unique records.

```
select * from
 (
    select ua.*,row_number() over (partition by p_id order by p_id ) row_num from 
    (
        select * from table1
        union all
        select * from table2
    )ua
) inner
where inner.row_num=1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.* FROM
(
 Select * from Table1
 union all
 Select * from table2
) A;
```

(or)

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3...coln FROM
(
 Select col1,col2,col3...coln from Table1
 union all
 Select col1,col2,col3...coln from table2
) A
GROUP BY A.col1,col2,col3...coln;
```

Comment: Both of these gave me ORA-22950: cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method.

Comment: 22950, 00000, "cannot ORDER objects without MAP or ORDER method"  
// *Cause:  an object type must have a MAP or ORDER method defined for   
//          all comparisons other than equality and inequality comparisons.  
// *Action: Define a MAP or ORDER method for the object type   
//

Answer (score -1):

UNION ALL will give duplicate values as well .. instead use UNION and see if you are facing the error

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned ideally an UNION would get it done. But I can't use UNION and Distinct(and it also seems like I can't use group by either) because there is an Object field in the table. You can not compare object fields using UNION and distinct.